# How to trace the history of changes to each data in ax2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, audit-trail, morph-x

i'm looking for  how AX2012 manage  Traceability .

I must trace the history of changes to each  data (modification date, user ID, IP address of the workstation).

I must also find  all the changes made by a given user in a given period and for directors, i must trace the history of the consultations they have made.

Best regards .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the [database logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362089.aspx) feature of Dynamics AX. But be warned, if you really want to track all data changes, this will decrease performance quite a bit. Also I don't think it logs the IP address of the user's workstation.

I'm not sure what you mean with the "history of consultations", could you provide more details?

Comment: what i'm looking for is how i should be able to trace the history of changes of an object to follow his state,( for exemple if i delete a object i can look 2 state of the same object with date modification and deleted by)

Comment: With "object" do you mean the application objects like forms, tables, classes? In that case you should use version control (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa639568.aspx)

Comment: it ok this post this post is very helpful using datebase logging [link]https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/alirazatechblog/archive/2013/07/01/dynamics-ax-2012-exploring-data-base-logging-for-insert-update-and-delete.aspx